# JavaFX (using fxml) and custom class doesn't load

Tags: javafx

I am attempting to upload my code, but having issues with IntelliJ and gitHub.  But the issue lies in the custom class not being found when I'm trying to load the second scene that contains a custom class.  Any examples out there that have multiple scenes and custom classes that can lead me down the right path?

I used this sample to start with, and then added my custom class (extends TextField), but as soon as i click the button to go to the second scene it crashes.

http://www.javafxtutorials.com/tutorials/switching-to-different-screens-in-javafx-and-fxml/

controller class

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.numberTextField;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

@FXML
Label lbl1;

@FXML
Button btn1;

@FXML
Label lbl2;

@FXML
Button btn2;

@FXML
numberTextField txtField1;

@FXML
public void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stage;
    Parent root;

    if (event.getSource() == btn1) {
        stage = (Stage) btn1.getScene().getWindow();

        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
    } else {
        stage = (Stage) btn2.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
}
```

fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import sample.numberTextField?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="250.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lbl2" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="29.0" text="This is scene 2" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="101.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClick" text="click to go to scene 1" />
            <numberTextField fx:id="txtField1" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="55.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Please post (not link to) enough code to reproduce the problem, and include the stack trace. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: maybe your .fxml file is missing the import statement of the custom class. without seeing the code, we can only guess

Answer (score -1):

It has been brought to my attention that the naming convention I used on my class file numberTextField needed to be altered to NumberTextField.  As soon as I did this, it began working as planned.  You have to love case sensitivity, and I don't remember seeing anything anywhere that stated I couldn't do that but all in all I have it working.

Thanks everyone for trying to help.